# Decimal values getting rounded off in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

I am facing a issue that is when am I giving a decimal value say 0.00344 it is getting rounded off to 0.03 but when I give 0.9765 it's  printing as given. The value should be given as mentioned because based on that we used to calculate amount.

Could anyone provide any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share code?  What is the expected behavior?

Comment: No idea why that happens. Could you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?

Comment: 0.00344 doesn't round to 0.3 in any rounding system

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a wild guess and ask are you talking about money?  "Used to calculate amount" makes it sound like you are computing something about money.  The fact that numbers are being rounded makes it sound like you are using floating point numbers.
In general, you should not use floating point data types to represent money:

https://husobee.github.io/money/float/2016/09/23/never-use-floats-for-currency.html

https://dzone.com/articles/never-use-float-and-double-for-monetary-calculatio

Comment: Yup yup, BigDecimal!